# How do I place a background image above body's background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set a background image in `body` and in `.wrap`. My question is how do I place a background above all them? It is done with CSS however I didn't figure it yet.

I place all my code in http://jsfiddle.net/7sdnU/

Thank you.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: try zindex for the image which you want to show above.

Answer (score 2):

With `z-index`:
http://jsfiddle.net/7sdnU/2/

Comment: Thank you for this! However it goes above images, textboxes and so on.  I tried `.image {
z-index:2;
}` with no luck. I updated the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7sdnU/14/

Answer (score 1):

The `html` element can also be styled, so you can shift the background layers back one element. Something like this:

```
html {
    background:url(bottom-background.png);
}
body {
    background:url(middle-background.png);
}
wrap {
    background:url(top-background.png);
}
/* Make sure everything takes up the whole viewport */
html, body, .wrap{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7sdnU/15/

You could also just add another wrapper div:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then apply the "top" background to `.inner`

However, CSS3 allows [multiple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/), so you may want to have a look at that - that's best solution if you can use it, but it's not fully supported.

Comment: After testing, the diagonal background goes only in wrap, not in the entire document...

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. You have to make `.wrap`'s height and width 100%, or if you can use CSS3 - multiple backgrounds is a great solution. My internet is cutting in and out so sorry I can't fix the demo...

Comment: Updated demo and post - give it a try, I'm still not sure what it's supposed to look like - the images are so small and subtle and my bad connection is making it hard to find better images for a demo.